# API calls to get statistics about the address delegated to a staking pool

Tags: proof-of-stake, staking-balance

Is there any API calls to get the statistics for certain address delegated to our staking pool?

Comment: Your question is more likely to get an answer if you are more specific as to exactly what information you are trying to retrieve.  Please edit your question as I think it has the potential to be valuable to others. If you have found your answer please provide it in order to share the knowledge.